# rank of a matrix based on rank of its submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $G\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, and assume ${\rm rank~}G=m$. Define
\begin{equation}
H\triangleq\left[\begin{array}{cc}{\rm Re~}G&{\rm Im~}G\\-{\rm Im~}G&{\rm Re~}G\end{array}\right]\in\mathbb{R}^{2m\times 2n}.
\end{equation}
Show that ${\rm rank~}H=2m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that for $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$,
$$
G(x - iy) = 0 \iff H \pmatrix{x\\y} = 0
$$

Comment: I think you want $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$ here, not $\mathbb C^n$, and $x-iy$ rather than $x+iy$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael you're right about that second point, but I think it still works with $x,y \in \Bbb C^n$. Note that we're considering the rank of these matrices over $\Bbb C$-vector spaces.

Comment: @RobertIsrael never mind, you're right; I wasn't reading closely.